# Three.js (r71) - Assigning the animation name to import it to three.js

Tags: animation, three.js

I was wondering if a Blender file contains many animations, how will the `three.js` library know which animation you want to open on the browser?

Because since the `THREE.AnimationHandler.add()` was deprecated, you should use the `THREE.Animation` (`mesh`, `geometry.animation`) function, which does not requires the animation name.

Does someone know how `three.js` does it?

Answer (score 1):

I have just figured this out. When calling the THREE.Animation (mesh, geometry.animations[0]) function, you are already calling the first animation in the array 'animations', so there is no need to call it by name.